# How to call custom javacript in ui_component form?

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.3

**Below is my field in Ui_component.**

```
<field name="received_amount" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">received_amount</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Received Amount</label>
                <dataScope>received_amount</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

So wanted to make calculation **onBlur** java script event and willing to set value to next field available in same form.

How can I achieve this ?